# join two tables with different number of rows(in sql server)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have two tables:
**A**(col1,col2,col3,col4)

**B**(col1,col2,col3,col4)

Table **A** has 4 records(rows) and **B** has 6 rows.I want to join them like this,for example join them in **C** table

**C**(**B.col1**,**B.col2**,A.col3,A.col4,B.col3,B.col4)  (tables have different values in records just col1 and col2 contains the same values)

when i join them on A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2 I take Cartesian product :(

P.S I want to have 6 rows in **C**,where B.col1,B.col2,B.col3,B.col4 have 6rows and A.col3,A.col4 have 4 rows and other 2 null

please help me..

Comment: what d oyou mean for join? what are the foreign keys, if any? the question is not clear.

Comment: The join you suggest - A.col1=B.col1 and A.col2=B.col2 - should work. Post the complete SQL you're trying.

Comment: Do you want a) all rows in B and any rows in A where the keys match or b) all rows from A and B that have a unique set of key values?

Comment: Thank you very much for your participation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

```
Select a.Col1,
       a.Col2,
       a.Col3,
       a.Col4,
       b.Col3,
       b.Col4

From TableA a
Full Outer Join TableB b on a.Col1 = b.Col1
                         And a.Col2 = b.Col2
```

**EDIT:**

"doesn't work" is not going to help anyone.  Maybe you could provide further details as to why it isn't working for you.

You could add some example data and the actual expected output to your question.

e.g

```
Create Table #TableA
(
Col1 
...
)

Insert Into #TableA
Values (...)
```

The clearer your question then the better the answers will be.  If people don't fully understand what your exact problem is and expected output you want then how are we supposed to provide you with a full and correct answer.

Comment: A reason why it does not work would be nice. What does this query you don't want it to do?

Comment: sorry,sorry.I was so hurry(because the problem had to be solved quickly) i missed important thing,that's why you weren't able to help me,it was my fault.
For this question,what I have actually asked,your answer works...Thank you..
But the problem was different and I have solved my problem:)

Comment: One never stops learning... "FULL" is a new one on me (and whilst I'm not even close to being an SQL Guru I'm not bad...)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT A.col1, A.col2, A.col3, A.col4, B.col3, B.col4
FROM A
FULL OUTER JOIN B on (A.col1 = B.col1 AND A.col2 = B.col2)
```

Comment: The need for an `OUTER JOIN` was added by an edit of the question shortly after my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use left outer join there.. But I have an additional question on how to populate the empty rows with some other values than NULL..