# TSQL - Join Three Tables with a single MTO column each

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, union, many-to-one

Alright so, I've got a charlie foxtrot of a three-db-merger no-frontend query needed, and after three subqueries to get what I need from the separate DBs, I realized I have literally no idea how to do multiple MTO combines without shitting everything up or having a frontend.

Also a note: OTO = One to One, MTO = Many to One
Sorry, really shouldda said that before the first edit.

SQLFiddle with sample data, a variant of both the JOIN-fail and UNION-fail, and a table with the goal description: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07e6a/1

---

### WHAT I'VE GOT

Three Tables:
**tblA: id, type, svc, other_data**
**tblB: id, type, svc**
**tblC: id, svc**

Rules they follow:
 0. **id** is a shared value between each table (usable for JOINing)
 1. **id**s must have an entry in **tblA** and **tblB**, while **tblC** only sometimes has an entry.
 2. All **svc** cols have a many-to-one relationship with **id**, and all other cols have a one-to-one relationship with **id**.
 3. **svc** in **tblA** and **tblB** *can be empty*, however, both tables provide at least one OTO value that always exists (and just shove null into their **svc** if they have none)
 4. No individual **id**'s **svc** 'array' in a single table has dupes (as in these tables are SELECT DISTINCT)
 5. **tblA.other_data** is actually multiple columns, but that shouldn't really matter at all, as any solution that supports one extra OTO column should support multiple trivially, since it's OTO. Worst case I can move these columns to a wrapper query. It's a non-issue.

---

### WHAT I WANT

**tblD: id, tblA.other_data, tblA.type, tblB.type, tblA.svc, tblB.svc, tblC.svc**

Where each **svc** column is MTO, but with the minimum number of rows possible to express this (ie, tblD should have a space complexity of Theta(Max(**tblA.svc**, **tblB.svc**, **tblC.svc**))).

Preferably, the order in which the **svc** are individually alphabetized, however, this isn't exactly mission critical (or, more precisely, having an unstable solution gives me a different problem to work on, rather than the one I've hit a wall on).

Essentially, I need a form of JOIN/UNION/WHATEVER that only treats certain columns as meaningful for any new columns added, rather than all columns. w*(x+y+z) rather than w*x*y*z, where w is the OTO information, and x, y, and z are all independent MTO sets of information.

---

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

Naively, the first thought is probably to just chain JOINs (***tblA*** INNER **tblB** LEFT **tblC**) on **id**, then outputting the columns I wanted
But doing this loses hard. For every **tblA.svc** there is, you get an instance of each **tblB.svc**, and for each of those you get an instance of each **tblC.svc**. Its Theta(a*b*c) size complexity is approaching oh-god-why territory even on small sets, and that complexity nukes whatever human-readability you might have had.

You could also try a wrapper around UNIONs, and making it not too terrible on performance by smartly 'caching'. You end up with either a single column (instead of three; tag the columns with which table it's from and you have my stopgap)), or a diagonal line of non-nulls for each record. Either way, space complexity is down to Theta(a+b+c) (much more bearable), and it's human-readable without a frontend filter. Still not ideal, however.

The third solution I've come up with (have not yet written) is to start with forming **tblD** with whichever of the three input tables has the most rows on average (to hopefully save on manual INSERTs later), then scan through the other two input tables using UPDATE when you can and INSERT when you can't. However, feels like a nuclear option that would make the JIT optimizer cry and the db disappointed in me, so I haven't tried since the previous solution was good enough.
The other reason I haven't implemented this yet is because this seems like such a 'simple' concept that I feel there's some built-in way to do this which will make the JIT happy and the db.... well, less annoyed.

Is that really the 'best way' to get what I want, other than getting a frontend to do it for the DB?

I mean, with a frontend, it's fairly trivial to do: pass up the OTO and three MTO tables sorted on **id**, walk OTO with three walk-till-next inners on the MTOs, giving you a single pass on all four tables and only writes on the output stream, with the DB doing even less in terms of response size (less data duplication)... But I don't have a frontend to exploit for this one (yet, anyways).

---

### SAMPLE DATA

This data is theoretical due to it being related to education outreach and I'd rather not out something accidentally. The 'type' field is just an idea of what could be there, it's not really important for the question as it's OTO and I could just throw fetching it into a wrapper if need be.

I've excluded a sample of **tblA.other_data** for simplicity

tblA:

```
id, type, svc
 1, 'li', 'Fin Aid/Scholarships'
 1, 'li', 'Tutoring: Math'
 1, 'li', 'Tutoring: English'
 2, 'fg', null
 3, 'fg', 'Career Counseling'
```

tblB:

```
id, type, svc
 1, 'g1', 'CollPrep'
 1, 'g1', 'Academic Support'
 2, 'g1', 'SciSum'
 2, 'g1', 'EngAcad'
 2, 'g1', 'MathAcad'
 3, 'g2', null
```

tblC:

```
id, svc
 3, 'Workshops'
```

Will produce tblD:

```
id, typeA, typeB, svcA                  , svcB              , svcC
 1, 'li' , 'g1' , 'Fin Aid/Scholarships', 'CollPrep'        , null
 1, 'li' , 'g1' , 'Tutoring: Math'      , 'Academic Support', null
 1, 'li' , 'g1' , 'Tutoring: English'   , null              , null
 2, 'fg' , 'g1' , null                  , 'SciSum'          , null
 2, 'fg' , 'g1' , null                  , 'EngAcad'         , null
 2, 'fg' , 'g1' , null                  , 'MathAcad'        , null
 3, 'fg' , 'g2' , 'Career Counseling'   , null              , 'Workshops'
```

NOTE: This table doesn't quite have the desired order, but as I mentioned earlier, I'm not too concerned about ordering outside of **id** (or one of the other OTO columns, which is trivial)

I would give sample code too, but I don't really see how it helps anything, since my question is more of a conceptual one than a "in this instance" one. I do get how actually seeing what I'm trying to do can help, though, hence the sample data.

Being perfectly honest, I'm also a little (very) embarrassed by how hacky the backend is... Let's just say I'm the first non-temp in this position for around ten years, most of the frontends are in MS Access, and the dbs look almost nothing like they did when there was last a stable person doing my job.

Pre-empting 'similar question' flags:

[join two tables with different number of rows(in sql server)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3776312/join-two-tables-with-different-number-of-rowsin-sql-server)
 - Kinda similar, but problem stems from a FULL OUTER JOIN use case, not multiple MTO relations.

[Join two tables, merge and transpose the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193028/join-two-tables-merge-and-transpose-the-result)
- Very similar... but all tricks used there depend on a known Many in your MTO relation, and a desire to transpose extra rows into columns. I cannot leverage the first (without setting an arbitrary max), and very much do not want the latter.

Comment: Please post sample data, the actual query you've tried so far, and an example of your desired results.  Your descriptions here are great, but you can't beat seeing the data.  (And for those who didn't figure it out:  MTO = many-to-one.  OTO = one-to-one.)

Comment: I think I've read this 3 times now and I still have no idea what your desired result is.  Sample data with expected result using that data would help me understand!

Comment: Updated. Tossed the MTO/OTO definition at the top (with an appology) and added sample data.

No actual code provided as it's pretty irrelevant imo. Though I might change my mind if more people ask.

Comment: It might help to take a look at http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @Morpheus *shrug* The lack of a data sample really was my bad, that one is instrumental.

But I'm honestly not seeing any merit in providing some "here's what I've done" code in this situation given the descriptions I've given of it. I mean, honestly, what more am I gonna do except turn the first one into: `(tblA a INNER JOIN tblB b ON a.id=b.id) LEFT JOIN tblC c ON a.id=c.id`
with explicit column naming added above it and the word FROM.
I mean, shit, I even implied that in the description. The second one is practically the same just with UNIONs.

Comment: This doesn't look to horrible but the kinda seems to be relying on an order which doesn't exist in the data posted. If you can turn that sample data into something consumable (sqlfiddle.com or by posting ddl and sample data here) along with an explanation of why a given row from table1 is related to a row in tableb we can sort this out. As indicated by Morpheus what is more important is providing the ability for us to write queries against this which we can't do as it is posted.

Comment: @SeanLange
I don't wanna be a dick, especially when asking for help, but literally rule 0 of my explanation of the tables covers that relationship question:
`0. **id** is a shared value between each table (usable for JOINing)`
I'll get on putting a sample on SQLFiddle right now and will toss that into the OP under sample code once it's ready.

Comment: It's your call mate. I understand you posted the explanation clearly. And if you were paying me I would gladly take the sample data and create the tables and such to hold it all. But since you are not paying me I would rather spend my time working on the sql instead of setting up the problem.

Comment: abluejelly -  I'm just sharing what I've learned in my short time on SO.  The  blog post I provided a link to begins with "If you want to have faster turnaround...".  I'm not saying what you posted is insufficient.  I will say @xQbert isn't the only one that had to read it more than once to get the gist.

Comment: @Morpheus Like I said, my bad on the lack of sample data. Also, didn't know about SQLFiddle till today, I'll definitely provide something like that from now on.
Added link to the SQLFiddle at the very top.

Comment: EDIT: There was a typo on the tblJoinFail example, the LJ is on a.id=c.id, not a.id=b.id

Comment: Thanks for the sql fiddle. It makes this a million times easier. Now for the question I eluded to earlier. It seems that you want row 1 from tblA and row1 from tblB. Not a problem. What defines the order of those rows? In other words, how do we know that 'Fin Aid/Scholarships' from tblA belongs on the same row as 'CollPrep' from tblB. Once this is answered the solution is quite simple.

Comment: @SeanLange Ah, THAT was what you meant, I thought you weren't seeing what the join target was. Apologies. It would be nice if the ordering is preserved (so the order in which tblA lists is the order tblD.svcA lists, tblB has the order for tblD.svcB, etc). Stability of this order isn't mission critical, but would be appreciated. I'll update the question.

Comment: By definition tables are unordered sets so there is no order to preserve. But if order is not horribly important I can post an answer shortly.

Comment: @SeanLange Er... right... Each one as alphabetical then. Sorry, I tend to think of them like 2D arrays, so if I had an order at the very start (alphabetical), it'd be maintained. My sample ignored this chalking it up to ORDER BY work later on, but I can see how it might cause problems. Will be *very* interested to see the unstable solution though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK thanks for posting some consumable data to work with. It makes this actually possible. Here is one way to do this. I had to create some CTEs to add ordering so we have something to know which row belongs to which row.

This isn't quite right because there are still some business rules that I don't quite fully understand. This should be close enough that you can tweak the last couple things into the way you want them.

```
with SortedTableA as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by svc) as RowNum
    from tblA
)
, SortedTableB as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by svc) as RowNum from tblB
)
, SortedTableC as
(
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by svc) as RowNum from tblC  
)

select isnull(a.id, b.id) as id
    , ISNULL(a.type, b.type) as typeA
    , ISNULL(b.type, a.type) as typeB
    , a.svc as svcA
    , b.svc as svcB
    , c.svc as svcC
from SortedTableA a
full outer join SortedTableB b on a.id = b.id and a.RowNum = b.RowNum
left join tblC c on c.id = a.id
order by isnull(a.id, b.id), ISNULL(a.RowNum, b.RowNum)
```

Comment: Sweet, thanks! Gave me a good two keywords to look up, too. (over, partition by). The joys of being fairly self-taught, and usually either fighting with Access or able to use a webend you're much more familiar with (plus thinking more in terms of conciseness of communication and ease of mutation than having the format perfect when leaving the DB).

Comment: In case you're curious, since I was already using temp tables to hold the fetched-from-different-dbs tables, I just went ahead and merged the row-numbering with the code generating those tables. This was exactly what I needed, sorry for the hard time at the start.